Revoke API Key or Disable Service when AWS Budget limit is exceeded
So I was looking into AWS and it's location service. Is there a way to revoke the access to an AWS service like the location service when the budget limit is exceeded? I know there are alerts which would trigger but it's way to easy that the mail is seen too late (weekends).
All the answers I've seen are quite old from three or more years ago. So I wanted to ask if there is now a way to set a fix budget or a maximum limit of requests which are allowed, for example for the AWS location service. And if there is not such a way, is there an easy way to revoke an api key for the location service?
And another side question: Is there also rate limiting in place from aws itself? I could think that it's quite easy for somebody to continue calling an endpoint rapidly. Do we have to implement rate limiting ourselves?

All AWS services implement some form of rate throttling afaik. Accounts often also have per-region, per service API limits (Location service quotas are described here).
